# Excel auto predicting where I want a number

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hoping to find an excel expert who can help me with this little issue.

Here is an example and I hope I explain it clearly.

I have three columns...A, B and C

A1 I enter a number and then go to B1 and do =A1 to input number there
I will do the same for A2 to A6....all will go into column B2 to B6
Then A7 I want it go to C7 (which I will do myself like the others) but the program automatically enters the data of A7 into B7 because it thinks it is smart and that I want the data to go there but I do not.

How do I disable this feature...what is it called? It basically auto predicts where I want to enter the data after entering data in one column (B in this example) after 6 times.

Thanks.

Comment: What is stopping you from entering the formula you want into that cell? Yes, it suggests the next obvious option, but you can just start typing and it'll dismiss those and allow you to enter your own values.

Answer (score 2):

Go To: File→Options→Advanced

Under Editing Options uncheck `Extend data Range Formats and Formulas`

[image]

Click OK